# Fedora 17 : Nautilus, after mount manually, device will not see again in Device section

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, nautilus

In Nautilus, I see left pane is useful. It contains shortcut to another place. Such as :

At **device** : I can see Windows Partition  (although I does not mount yet) or at **my computer**, some shortcut to go Home/Desktop/Documents/Downloads....

When I mount Windows partitions in Nautilus (double click, a confirm windows appear to ask...). After I mount, I still can see this device in left pane.

But, if I mount by hand, (I do by hand because I want auto mount every time I start using Linux). I do this  by go to terminal and type :

> mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/C

It will lost this icon in left pane. Of course, no problem here, but if I want to go to these location, I must go to by hand : root -> mnt --> C

So, does anything if I mount by hand, and still can see it in Nautilus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be visible in Nautilus you should mount it where `udisks2` mounts it, i. e. under `/run/media/USERNAME/`where `USERNAME` is (obviously) your user name. Something like this:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /run/media/USERNAME/C
```